# External monitor (connected via USB-C, nVidia GPU) refresh only with mouse moving or animation

Tags: nvidia, multiple-monitors, 23.04

I have a laptop with AMD 5600H and nVidia RTX3060 running Ubuntu 23.04 (Kernel 6.2) and an external monitor connected via USB-C port.

The laptop's internal screen, which is connected to integrated AMD GPU, runs and refreshes normally. However the external monitor connected to nVidia GPU will constantely freeze, and only refresh either when the mouse cursor is moving on the screen, or when mouse cursor is showing animation ("busy").

The nVidia driver used is the proprietary driver 535.54. I tried switching to novaevu but the external screen will keep flashing in white.

Comment: The problem is not present when using Wayland instead of XOrg. So it seems to be a compatibility problem between XOrg and nVidia driver.